# How to use Color Bar for String Values in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I like to color the backgrounds of the cells which has similar values. There are huge no. of such values so it is not possible to create condition/rule for each. I am looking for a shortcut. Like this -

[image: Image description]

Comment: You want all of them to be the same color or all of them to be different colors? Like cat, cat, dog, dog all be yellow OR cat, cat be yellow and dog, dog be red?

Comment: cat, cat be yellow and dog, dog be red @Raystafarian

Comment: [check here first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177752/excel-2010-vba-highlight-with-different-colors-cells-with-different-dupplicate-v)

Comment: @Raystafarian That's good but I was looking for some in-built Microsoft thing :P